# Conversor de Decimal para Hexadecimal Scratch

Tags: scratch

Olá Amigos estou tentando fazer um conversor de Decimal para Hexadecimal em scratch só que 15 decimal da certo acima desse numero só mostra uma parte do valor[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você achou a variável "adicione a"
Eu uso a versão do Scratch 1.4 e a online. Não achei essa variável.

Comment: O seu algoritmo está com problemas. Segue um link para um projeto parecido que pode ajudar: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/235404524/